# How do you create new strings in Kotlin equivalent to C#

Tags: c#, string, kotlin

I am busy learning Kotlin and as always the first step is a console application.
In C# you can create a new string of char quite easily:
`return new string('-',10);` for example.

How do you achieve the same in Kotlin ? I've read through the documentation for the Kotlin String class and can't seem to find an easy option.

Thanks for considering the question.

Comment: Along with the answer of @Andrei if you want to like repeat like 100 or thousand times, you can have a look at the [StringBuilder](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-string-builder/) its append function and toString function. It is optimized well for adding multiple strings and build at last.

Comment: This is an excellent idea, I'll definitely use this for larger string manipulations. I can see the use cases already. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`repeat`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/repeat.html) function:

```kotlin
"-".repeat(10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!